# .NET Date without Time - is there one, or should I not need one?

Tags: .net, datetime, date

I'm doing some domain modelling and coming across a property which to my mind would be best exposed as a Date rather than a DateTime, without a time component.

Is there a good reason why there is no such type in the Framework? It was deemed a good enough idea to add a Date type to SQL Server. Also, if someone knows of a handy implementation of a Date class, please let me know!

*2018 edit: I now tackle this using a Value Object Type:*

```
public class Date : ValueOf<DateTime, Date>  //Install-Package ValueOf
{ 
    protected override void Validate() 
    { 
        if (Value.Date != Value) throw new ArgumentException(); 
    } 
}

...

var date = Date.From(someDateTime);
```

Comment: One is coming to .NET 6.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314309/a-type-for-date-only-in-c-sharp-why-is-there-no-date-type/66806020#66806020

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There wasn't one at the time the question was asked, and yes, there should be one. Fortunately, as of .NET 6 we have [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly) and [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly).

I don't believe there was a good reason other than that [the date and time API in .NET isn't very good](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) in my (very biased) view.

The [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project of which I'm the primary maintainer has `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`, as part of a rather larger set of types.

Comment: Now all we need to do is get MS to deprecate the old classes :)

Comment: @mcintyre321: Well, I'd love to talk to someone on the BCL team about a new API for .NET 6 :) (I suspect it's way too late for .NET 5...)

Comment: Please do. I remember the dreaded day DST changed and all our users' recurring meetings shifted an hour.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, how do I convert between `LocalDate` and `DateTime` and vice-versa?

Comment: @RosdiKasim: Within Noda Time? `date.AtMidnight().ToDateTimeUnspecified()`

Comment: WOW that was instant... even Google instant search is slower than you. thanks for the help.

Comment: .Net 6 will introduce DateOnly and TimeOnly classes: 
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-dateonly-and-timeonly-in-dotnet-6

Answer (score 8):

In a database storage capacity is more important, so a `date` type that uses less space than a `datetime` may make sense. In an application you rarely have the need for saving those few bytes.

You could rather easily make a `Date` type that converts to and from `DateTime`, but only stores the days internally. Something like:

```
public struct Date {

  private int _days;

  private Date(int days) { _days = days; }

  public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date) {
    return DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(date._days);
  }

  public static implicit operator Date(DateTime dateTime) {
    return new Date((int)(dateTime - DateTime.MinValue).TotalDays);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I created a simple [Date struct](https://github.com/claycephus/csharp-date) for times when you need a simple date without worrying about time portion, timezones, local vs. utc, etc.

https://github.com/claycephas/csharp-date

Comment: While nice, internally this solution uses Datetime nonetheless. I hoped to spare some bits in a large set, using Date only, but this solution does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToShortDateString() method. If you need a property for a grid or something, make a readonly property which just returns yourDate.ToShortDateString() and you got it!

Answer (score -1):

VB.NET has this type, the `Date` data type. I believe this was here as a requirement for grandfathering VB6 app code which contained this type and not the `DateTime` type we use in .NET.

**Date** Data Type (Visual Basic):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Comments on the downvote please? The tags say `.net` and this namespace continuing this type is accessible by both VB.NET and C# and does what the OP wanted: "a Date rather than a DateTime, without a time component"

Comment: "A variable or constant of the Date data type holds both the date and the time."

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is one. `Date`,`DateTime` (VB) and `DateTime` (C#) both have a function called `Date` on them that return only the date portion of the date/time.

There is also a `Time` function so you can use them for both and return the date/time parts separately.

Comment: It is true and I don't know why (highly ranked) selected answer says it is not possible. [DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

Comment: Because DateTime.Date is error prone. You will forget it a some point!

Comment: DateTime.Date returns a DateTime object. The OP asked for a Date object, not a Date property of an existing object. DateTime.Date really returns a DateTime object with 0 time component. But this means that applications can't tell the difference betwee "midnight on this day" and "This day without any time specified" ... which means they don't know if they should display the time portion or not, etc. There are also problems converting "DateTime.Date" between timezones, where you wouldn't want it to change, but might show 11PM the day before, if you display on a computer in another timezone.

Answer (score -4):

There isn't really any need for one - just use a date with the time component set to zero (i.e. midnight of the previous day), or just ignore the time component completely.

For example you can use `DateTime.Today` to get today's date (as opposed to `DateTime.Now`)

Comment: In that case there's no need for integer types either - we can just use floating point types and ignore everything after the decimal point, right? Likewise there's no need for a string type - just use a byte array and decode it whenever you need to. `Date` is conceptually a different type to `DateTime` - it makes sense to add minutes to a `DateTime`, but not to a `Date`. It makes sense to think of a `DateTime` in a particular time zone, but not a `Date`. I could go on :) It's incredibly important to be able to let your code express the concepts it's dealing with. DateTime doesn't do that.

Comment: @Jon You shouldn't use floats instead of integers because rounding errors add up (1.1 * 10 = 11, as opposed to 1 * 10 = 10), you shouldn't use byte arrays for strings as there is no real consideration for unicode. *Ideally* there would be a `Date` type, but its not the end of the world that there isn't.

Comment: Add lots of minutes to a DateTime and you'll get to another date too - another sort of rounding error. Of course you should only perform integer arithmetic with those integer values... shame you can't tell what's meant to be an integer and what isn't if all you've got is floats. Have you done much work with dates and times in .NET? The code is hard to read and understand because DateTime is used for everything - local times, UTC, dates, times, etc. DateTimeOffset helps, but not nearly enough.