# How do I deal with dates-only in javascript when it keeps appending a time value?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a bunch of `date` fields (not `datetime`) in SQL Server. When they are fetched by the web server and sent to the client as JSON a time stamp is appended automatically. So instead of receiving just `2016-09-27` I get `2016-09-27T00:00:00`.

When the user interacts with the uiBootstrap calendar control it automatically parses that string into a javascript date object and applies a 4 hour offset for the timezone. When this is sent back to the server it's sent as `2016-09-26T20:00:00`. Now my date is off by a day. Also the next time it's fetched it will happen again. But this time it will start at `2016-09-26T00:00:00` and will roll back to `2016-09-25T20:00:00`. Each cycle between client and server loses a day.

How do I keep my dates from changing? I'm looking at moment.js but so far haven't really figured out how it can help me.

EDIT

I've setup a test function to try different methods of converting datetimes back and forth.

```
            console.log('JSONDate: ' + JSONDate);
            var dt = new Date(JSONDate);
            console.log('JS Converted Date: ');
            console.log(dt);
            console.log('Date converted back to string: ' + dt.toISOString());
```

Here's the output:

```
JSONDate: 2016-10-02T00:00:00
JS Converted Date: Sun Oct 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Date converted back to string: 2016-10-02T04:00:00.000Z
```

In this example the date is now 4 hours ahead.

EDIT 2

Web server is running .net, specifically WebAPI 2. I'm using Entity Framework 6 to communicate between web server and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: parse the dates to UTC then timezone will be irrelevant

Comment: This is where I suggest passing around timestamps rather than date strings or date objects to avoid timezone issues.

Comment: Can you tell me what technologies your web server is using?  Code would be appreciated.

Comment: @MattJohnson I've update the question with that info. There's no code to show because I don't do anything with the dates on the server. .NET handles the conversion between JSON and C# classes/EF entities and then those are forwarded directly to the DB via LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your dates would be serialized in the JSON as just dates.  Instead of `2016-10-02T00:00:00`, you'd have `2016-10-02`.  The problem is that .NET doesn't have a built in `Date` type.  It only has `DateTime`.  There are alternatives, such as `LocalDate` in Noda Time, as discussed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34751042/634824).

However, assuming you don't want to change anything on the back-end, the way to handle this is just to make sure the input date/time is treated as *local time*, and never converted to/from UTC. This *should* be the default behavior when you parse the string into a `Date` object when the string is like `2016-10-02T00:00:00`, but the behavior has [changed a few times over the years](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/06/17/javascript-date-parsing-changes-in-es6/), so if you are potentially dealing with older browsers, you may get some that interpret it as UTC instead.

As far as output goes, the `toISOString` method of the `Date` object *always* outputs in UTC - which is the source of your conversion error.  If you want an ISO8601 string in local time - you'd have to construct one yourself using the various accessor functions (`getFullYear`, etc.), handling zero-padding, and ensuring months are incremented to be 1-based instead of 0-based.

The easier solution is to use moment.js, which can handle this for you.

```
var d = moment('2016-10-02T00:00:00').toDate();  // now you have a `Date` object

var s = moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss"); // now you have a string again
```

Of course, if you don't need the time portion, you can omit it from the format string and the rest should still work out ok.

Answer (score -1):

You could try getting the offset and applying it back to the date. Something like this:

```
var d = new Date('2016-09-27'); //Mon Sep 26 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
new Date(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000) //Tue Sep 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: This can fail due to parsing differences between different browsers, and also uses the offset of the UTC midnight value, not the local midnight value. So it might fail near certain DST transitions.  In general, be very careful with this "epoch shifting" technique, as it is usually done wrong.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for making me aware of this.