# Remove Time from a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a `Datetime` object and I want to remove time part from it. I tried the following line of code but still `auth.dob` contains `time`. How can I just set `2017-01-01` in it?

```
auth.dob = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-01-01").Date;
```

Comment: It will have to just be a string. The DateTime struct is a for both parts..... See [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) if you want something better!

Comment: I don't know the API whatsoever - but [this local date](http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html) seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: A `DateTime` object has time properties.  Its name implies this.  *Why* do you think you need to do this?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: what type is auth.dob?

Comment: How you check that `auth.dob` still contains time?

Comment: What you are doing is fine.  Depending on what you intend to do with it, it's not even necessary.  E.g. if you want to output the date of birth, the format parameters can be used to just display the date.  If checking if it's a user's birthday, you can just compare the day and month elements (might want to think about people born of the 29th February).

Comment: @MartinBrown DateTime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A type for Date only in C# - why is there no Date type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314309/a-type-for-date-only-in-c-sharp-why-is-there-no-date-type)

Comment: @HumaAli: What you have here is called an XY Problem.  This same question is asked surprisingly often on Stack Overflow, and it's almost always because the programmer is too focused on their attempted solution to think about the actual problem being solved.  Often times there is no problem at all, or it's something as simple as using a format string when displaying the value.  So what is the problem being solved here?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly .Net does not include a type that only stores the date. Generally we use [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the time to midnight. Then when you output the value you just omit the Time when displaying it see [DateTime.ToString(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.ToShortDateString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DateTime.ToLongDateString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx).

While this works it does lead to all sorts of confusion. I've often felt it would have been better to have a Date struct a Time struct and a DateTime struct that was a composition of the other two. But sadly that isn't the case.

There is the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library, but that is probably overkill in this case.

Alternatively you can role your own and store the day, month and year as separate numeric variables.