# Unable to extract date part from Date type

Tags: c#

I converted String to Date in my c# code and now all values in my column are of date type.
I wanted to show only date in a column but still see date + hrs, e.g. now shows 20.10.2020 00:00:00 and I wanted only 20.10.2020.

I try to extract date part only but it doesn't work. I must return Date type btw, not string. My attempts shown below (this code works - converts to a Date but not in desired format, I mean only date part):

```
        public DateTime? ConvertDate(decimal? date) 
        {

            if (date == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {

                string dateString = date.ToString();
                string year = dateString.Substring(0, 4);
                string month = dateString.Substring(4, 2);
                string day = dateString.Substring(6, 2);

                int yearInt;
                int monthInt;
                int dayInt;

                bool successYear = Int32.TryParse(year, out yearInt);
                bool successMonth = Int32.TryParse(month, out monthInt);
                bool successDay = Int32.TryParse(day, out dayInt);

                DateTime convertedDate = new DateTime(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);

                //string shortDateTime = convertedDate.ToString("d");  i tried this but no difference in showing date

                //DateTime shortDate = Convert.ToDateTime(shortDateTime); i also tried this but no difference in showing date


                return convertedDate;



            }
        }
```

Comment: What about `"d"` format wasn't as expected? According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1), this should have been exactly what you want? When you tried, did you actually return the string? Nothing you do to the DateTime struct itself will change display. You need to format the datetime using some variation of `ToString`.

Comment: There is no separate "date part". A `DateTime` is basically just an `Int64` value counting Ticks since `DateTime.MinValue`. -- "I wanted to show only date in a column" - then it's up to you to give that column a certain format. Any kind of display means a call to `ToString` some way or another. And usually, that call should happen as late as possible (on the "client" side UI when actually displaying it) and only then the formatting should be applied. Until then, work with a `DateTime`, where you will always have the "time part"; which by convention is set to midnight.

Comment: You wrote that you must return Date type but you are actually returning DateTime.
If you absolutely have to return DateTime, then you can't really do this, since DateTime has a date and a time in it by default.

Comment: Looking for [ToShortDateString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netcore-3.1)? My bad "_I must return Date type btw, not string._", the this may help you ["_A type for Date only in C# - why is there no Date type?_"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314309/)

Comment: Then as written above, you could use ToString("d") that returns a string though.

Comment: @ÁdámMaul While that's correct, it is culture-dependend. So if you want "dd.MM.yyyy" format regardless of culture, you have to do a little bit more. Not sure if that's the case here, though.

Comment: If this method is meant to return a `DateTime` (or `DateTime?`), then there is no way to have it "without a time part" (_only_ with the time part set to all zeros). If you want to **display** only the date, then that is a whole different problem that needs to be solved at a completely different place. Namely  the UI and by giving the `DateTime` value a format (and most likely a formatprovider) in the call to `ToString`.

Comment: _"I converted String to Date"_ also contradicts `public DateTime? ConvertDate(decimal? date)` - what are you _actually_ trying to do here?

Comment: Btw. stuff like `string dateString = date.ToString(); string year = dateString.Substring(0, 4); [...]` might work on _your_ computer with _your_ cultural settings, but is likely to fail spectacularily if you run it on different machines with different settings. Other culutres use different arrangements of the date parts. "MM/dd" vs. "dd/MM". And who knows where the year is supposed to be... when using `ToString` (and `Parse`/`TryParse`) on an `IFormattable`, you will spare yourself much headache if you consistently specify a format and a format provider (like `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A type for Date only in C# - why is there no Date type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314309/a-type-for-date-only-in-c-sharp-why-is-there-no-date-type)

Comment: (see also: https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: I have 2 more issues: 1st - i need date format for date comparison (I compare date from this field I wrote about with filed where user can choose date ona datepicker), 2nd - I take this date and need to insert it into 'input type=date' . This format with time doesn't allow me to do it, I need pure date

Comment: @Muska you've just perfectly described an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you ask how to do the actual thing you're trying to do (rather than how you _think_ it might be achieved) you'll get a far better answer.

Comment: If you are trying to convert a input like : 20200101 into 01/01/2020.
For that you can drop the SubString part and simply use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact)Methods.
Where you provide a string and it's format and get a date in return. 

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HWdHgq)

Comment: I used ```[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]``` in my model it solved the rpoblem with displaying date format

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you should use date formatting.

```
string DateToDateString(DateTime date)
{
    return string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
   //dd day, 
   //MM month
   //yyyy year
 
   //If you need,
   //HH for hour (24h)
   //hh for hour (12h)
   //mm for minute

}
```

Comment: In a format string, the `'/'` is the placeholder for the actual date separator of the used format provider. If none is given, the "Current(UI?)Culture" of the current thread is used. If you run this for example in a german environment, where the date separator is a dot, you will get `"20.10.2020"` which might be different from what you'd expect. So when in doubt, better specify the intended format provider explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for these precisions Corak.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime **represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.**
As per my understanding and research on microsoft's website, When you return value as DateTime you would always be having time with it. But as you told, you want it to be only date part it's  not possible as of now. For this formatters have been provide which will return the value in string format. If you want to just display it use formatter. With DateTime there are also different methods provided like add, substract which is not possible in string representation.

Answer (score -1):

You would write your own custom DateTime class and override its ToString() method in order to return only Date parts.

```
    public class CustomDate
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Day:00}.{Month:00}.{Year:0000}";
        }
   }
```

Comment: Seriously, _no_.

Comment: Why would that be better than simply formatting it though? He/She would just have the exact same properties, and it wouldn't be compatible with a lot of things DateTime is compatible with..

Comment: And loose TimeZone, Simple conversion. Substraction that give TimeSpan. Advance formating. Support for globalization. You loose day of the week, week of month etc.

Comment: That's terrible advice! First of all, you now have a class with mutable members instead of an immutable struct. Then you'd need to convert DateTimes to an instance of this, all the time. You lose all the convenient operators, formatting, globalization ... And on top: you don't need it _at all_.

Comment: I will store a DateTime internally. because it's safer at handling date. Like 28/02/2020 + 1.. Like this https://github.com/supersonicclay/csharp-date/blob/master/CSharpDate/Date.cs

Comment: As per question, Value should be in DateTime Format only. This returns string.

Comment: @anandshukla The thing is, as per question, it is not solvable. `DateTime` will always have a Time part, even if it is 0. And the default string representation will show it. So you either return a formatted string or `DateTime` (or `DateTime?`) and accept that formatting is a "last step" UI thing.